# Refresh new element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

To make sure that the items that are dynamically created are intercepted by the events using the method `.on`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.element',...
```

But if I wanted to intercept the new elements of a plugin, how can you do?

For example using the plugin tooltip bootstrap:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lughino/t77ez/1/)

if I create a new element, to ensure that this is intercepted by the tooltip plugin I have to call again:

```
$('a').tooltip();
```

This is a system not as good as I have to continually repeat code for every new element that I create ..

So there is a way to refresh the elements?

Comment: As remember there is $('').trigger("zupdate","..."). To update your what ever element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `selector` delegation option.

See the docs: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

```
$('body').tooltip({
    placement:'bottom',
    selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]'
});
```

Demo: <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: I didn't know that twitter bootstrap include this kind of shortcut for delegating their plugin. This is a nice one, thx for the info!

Comment: Thank you!
This solves the problem with tooltip!
But my question was a bit more general ..
I thought there was a way to be able to perform the refresh of new elements with any plugin.
In fact if I use another plugin that hasn't a method to do this I do not know how to do it if you do not re-initialize the plugin all times: `$('a').plugingeneric();`

Comment: @Lughino it can works only on plugins that implement it; if not you have to reinit the plugin

Comment: @Lughino it belongs to the author of the plugin to incoporate or not some kind of delegation

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lughino/t77ez/1/), i'm using:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', 'a', function(){$(this).tooltip();});
```